# Cannot add value to file object size property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a file object in JavaScript and I'm not able to put value in the size property.

```
vm.allFiles[key] = new File([], value.fileName, {
    size: value.fileSize // this doesn't work
});
vm.allFiles[key].current = 'done';
vm.allFiles[key].fileID = value.id;
// vm.allFiles[key].size = value.fileSize - this gives error of Cannot assign to read only property 'size' of object '#<File>'
```

Edit: In regards to the answers.

The `value` returned from the server is just `Object` and not of `File` object kind. The reason why I need to have it as File object because new uploaded files will be stored to `vm.allFiles` array.

Comment: That's a unexpected behavior, and wrong use of the File constructor. Also the constructor is [not supported everywhere](http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api). I would advice you to build your own plain object/class if the file/blob isn't going to contain the content itself. You won't be able to use the FileReader or the FormData for pretty much anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `size` property on `File` is inherited from `Blob`. The `size` property on `Blob` is read-only.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

If you want to force the property to be overwritten, you can do this:

```
Object.defineProperty(vm.allFiles[key], 'size', {
    value: value.fileSize
});
```

Answer (score -1):

> A Blob object represents a file-like object of immutable, raw data. Blobs represent data that isn't necessarily in a JavaScript-native format. The File interface is based on Blob, inheriting blob functionality and expanding it to support files on the user's system.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob